# Javascript Array in for loop returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I loop this array with a for loop it somehow gives me undefined in

```
updateField(this.value, vehicles[i]+"_brand"
```

While

```
$("#"+vehicles[i]+"_year").change(function(){
```

Does get the right values of the array. How can this be and how can I solve this?

```
var vehicles = new Array();
    vehicles[0] = "auto";
    vehicles[1] = "truck";
    vehicles[2] = "motor";

for(var i = 0;i < vehicles.length;i++){
    $("#"+vehicles[i]+"_year").change(function(){
       updateField(this.value, vehicles[i]+"_brand", 1, 2, this.parentNode.id), resetBelow(0,'auto'), show('auto_brand');
    });
}
```

Comment: undefined what exactly?

Comment: what is vehicles[i]+"_brand"

Comment: There's nothing that "this" is referring to, "this.value".

Comment: lol, so many issues with this one :D

Comment: not true - `this` refers to `$("#"+vehicles[i]+"_year")`

Comment: Trust me the only issue is the vehicles[i]+"_brand" and I think thats because its in the jquery change function

Comment: duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1):

The time the change event will be fired `vehicles[i]` will be evaluated again and you will be having the last value of `i`.

Change

```
vehicles[i]+"_brand"
```

To

```
this.id.split('_')[0]+"_brand"
```

Comment: This returns in the console: Object [object Object] has no method 'split'

Comment: I missed the id check my updated answer.

Comment: I think it doesnt get the id I get: "Cannot call method 'split' of undefined" now. Sorry im not good with js but this does seem like the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're having commas where semicolons should be to me:

```
updateField(this.value, vehicles[i]+"_brand", 1, 2, this.parentNode.id); resetBelow(0,'auto'); show('auto_brand');
```

... or maybe your `updateField()` function has more parameters and you simply closed the function prematurely?